# Why was it difficult to initially phrase compactness?

Tags: mathematics, topology

> From beginnings of topology, it was clear that the closed interval $\left[a,b \right]$ of the real line had a certain property that was crucial for proving such theorems as the maximum value theorem and the uniform continuity theorem.(Sect-26, Munkres)

What was actually the difficulty faced by mathematicians in precisy-fying the intuitive idea of continuity?

Comment: See [*A pedagogical history of compactness*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.7.619) by Manya Raman-Sundstrom (2015) **AND** [*La genèse du théorème de recouvrement de Borel*](http://www.numdam.org/article/RHM_2005__11_2_163_0.pdf) by Bernard Maurey and Jean-Pierre Tacchi (2005) **AND** [*The Borel theorem and its generalizations*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-32/issue-5/The-Borel-theorem-and-its-generalizations/bams/1183487130.full) by Hildebrandt (1926).

Comment: The difficulty was that what was precisified was *not* the intuitive idea of continuity, as reactions to Weierstrass's nowhere differentiable continuous function and Peano's square filling curve showed. Hermite "*turned away with fright and horror from this lamentable evil*", Poincare said that "*logic sometimes makes monsters*" and complained that "*one invents them purposely to show up defects in the reasoning of our fathers*", and only that. What eventually happened was a triumph of technical utility over intuition, and it took time for that utility to become apparent in various contexts.